# Virtual network setup with Guest OS installed in virtual box

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-vista, virtualbox

I am a Linux newbie. I have just installed Ubuntu inside Vista using Virtual box. Everything is working fine. now i wanted to establish a client server (virtual) network with a guest os (ubuntu) to connect to the cassandra server installed in ubuntu.

Can someone guide me on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Virtualbox question - have a read of http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

You'll either want NAT networking and specify which ports to forward, or full bridged network.

Answer (score 0):

menu > run > type in cmd.exe

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Sun\xVM VirtualBox\"

VBoxManage.exe setextradata "NAMEVM" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/Cassandrah/HostPort" 9160

VBoxManage.exe setextradata "NAMEVM" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/Cassandra/GuestPort" 9160

VBoxManage.exe setextradata "NAMEVM" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/Cassandra/Protocol" TCP
```

casandra client can now connect to localhost.

Or use "Bridged networking" and connect directly to ubuntu